# I'm trying to pull a aproject from my pc via git (command line) to github. but I can't get the link from github

Tags: git, github, pull-request

On my PC, I have already made these steps:

```
git init 
git add "the directory name"
git commit -m "****"
```

[image: github screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

What you see is a pull request page, not the project page itself.

Consider instead, for instance, [`clayakers/Dasmoto-Project`](https://github.com/clayakers/Dasmoto-Project): (replace clayakers with your GitHub username): this is where you find the URL (HTTPS or SSH) to use:

[image: URL]

You would need, assuming the GitHub repo is still empty, to do:

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
git remote add origin https://github.com/clayakers/Dasmoto-Project
git push -u origin/master
```